# Probability of remaining elements out of an arrangement

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let's say we distribute $r$ distinguishable balls into $n$ cells at random, multiple occupancy being permitted. The probability that the first cell contains exactly $k$ balls is given by:
$\binom{r}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k(1-\frac{1}{n})^{r-k}$

I understand the following:
The probability of putting a ball in the first cell is $\frac{1}{n}$, and the probability of putting a ball in another cell is $1 - \frac{1}{n}$. We can arrange the $k$ out of $r$ balls in $\binom{r}{k}$ ways. Since we put $k$ balls in the first cell we get $\binom{r}{k}(\frac{1}{n})^k$ $(*)$. If I understand it correctly, we then multiply $(*)$ with $(1-\frac{1}{n})^{r-k}$, because there is an intersection: putting k balls into the first cell puts the remaining balls in the other cells.

But why are we not also multiplying $(*)$ by the ways we can arrange the remaining $k-r$ balls over the remaining $(n-1)$ cells?

Comment: You have a typo in the very first formula.  It should say $\left(\frac1n\right)^\color{red}k$

Answer (score 1):

We already mutiplied by the ways we can arrange the remaining $r-k$ balls over remaining $n-1$ cells. It is $(n-1)^{r-k}$.

You can find total number of arrangements on $r$ balls as $n^r$. Total number of arrangements such that  the first cell contains exactly $k$ balls is 
$$
\binom{r}{k}\cdot 1\cdot (n-1)^{r-k}
$$
Indeed, there are $\binom{r}{k}$ combinations of $k$ balls from $r$, these $k$ chosen balls can be addressed to first cell by a single way, and the other $r-k$ balls can be distributes ampng the rest $n-1$ cells by $(n-1)^{r-k}$ ways.

Divide it by the total nomber of arrangements and get probability
$$
\frac{\binom{r}{k}\cdot (n-1)^{r-k}}{n^r} = \binom{r}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{n^k}\cdot \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{r-k}
$$

The other way to get this formula is to look at binomial distribution. There are $r$ independent Bernoulli trials: the success for single ball is to fall into the first cell. The success probability is $\frac1n$, the failure probability is $1-\frac1n$. The probability to have exactly $k$ successes is 
$$
\binom{r}{k}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^k\cdot \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{r-k}
$$